# Problems with certificate with private key , IIS, AppPool and user

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, asp.net, certificate

I have Windows 2003, IIS 6.0 , ASP.NET application using Certificate with Private Key.

User in domain "domainCompany\Pre_Certificado" install Certificate in Store Local Machine.

domainCompany\Pre_Certificado is Administrator, in IIS_WPG group, has Local Policies: “Log on as Service“

I configure AppPool Identity in IIS 6.0 for : domainCompany\Pre_Certificado

ASP.NET application executes using the identity :: domainCompany\Pre_Certificado

I recycle AppPool and execute application, I get 
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Cannot find the certificate and private key for decryption

If I test again, log in session in server IIS, using domainCompany\Pre_Certificado  user, I call page in ASP.NET application and all is OK.

(note: log in server IIS using Terminal Server)

But if log off session in server IIS (user: domainCompany\Pre_Certificado), I get the same error:

System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Cannot find the certificate and private key for decryption

Any suggestions ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to install the SSl on your local system from which you are running the application.